# Отличия swagger и openAPI

Tags: swagger, openapi

В чём отличия между [swagger](https://github.com/swagger-api) и [openAPI](https://github.com/OpenAPITools)? Это два разныъ проекта. Но на [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAPI_(%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)) сказано, что это одно и то же.

Comment: почему минусовали? Вроде понятный вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идея, смысл задачи одни - описание спецификации. Swagger - запатентованный коммерческий продукт. OpenAPI бесплатный вариант Swaggerа. Есть небольшие различия в синтаксисе но в целом идея идентична.

Answer (score 4):

дополню

Swagger - продукт и спека версии 2.0, openAPI - это спека Swagger версии 3.0 и выше

Swagger 2.0 и OpenApi(Swagger 3.0) отличаются синтаксисом и возможностями. В 3.0 появились компоненты и поддержка Multiple Servers\Hosts

подробнее о различиях: https://blogs.sap.com/2018/01/05/open-api-spec-2.0-vs-3.0/